# How to sort a collection of an object that has a predecessor field?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, linked-list

Suppose that I have a `Color` class

```
class Color
{
    int id;
    string name;
    int? predecessorId;
    Color(_id, _name, _predecessorId)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
        predecessorId = _predecessorId;
    }
}
```

The purpose of the predecessor ID is that I can have a collection of colors and have them sorted arbitrarily. (I did not design this data structure.)

Suppose I have the following seven colors:

```
var colors = new []
{
    new Color(0, "red", null),
    new Color(1, "orange", 0),
    new Color(2, "yellow", 1),
    new Color(3, "green", 2),
    new Color(4, "blue", 3),
    new Color(5, "indigo", 4),
    new Color(6, "violet", 5)
}
```

Now, suppose that I receive data from an external source.  The data looks like the above, but the colors don't necessarily come in the array in the order that the predecessorId field.  However, I will always assume that the predecessorId values always form an unbroken linked list.

Given an array of seven of these color objects, how do I sort them so that the first one is the one with no predecessor, the second one has the first one as its predecessor, and so on.

I am well aware that there are any number of ways to skin this cat, but I am using C# .net and I would like to use the built-in framework classes as much as possible to avoid writing more code that must be maintained.

Comment: Create a [`Comparer<Color>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47(v=vs.110).aspx) class and use built-in array sorting.

Comment: `var orderedEnumberable = colors.OrderBy( c => c.predecessorId)`

Comment: @ryanyuyu's solution here would only work if we could guarantee that the predecessorIds are always in numeric order.  If I changed the predecessor IDs to reverse the order, it wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon I'm not sure what you mean. I just built your sample application (Although I re-organized your `colors[]` so they're not in order by predacessorId). Upon calling `OrderBy(c => c.predacessorId)` it is correctly sorted from `null` -> 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: [`OrderBy(c => c.predacessorId)` output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa1uQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Pick the first (and hopefully unique) color by finding the one with `predecessorId == null`. Then find the next by indexing a dictionary of predecessorId to color until no more matches are found:

```
var current = colors.Single(c => c._predecessorId == null);
var sorted = new List<Color> { current };

var colorsByPredecessorId = colors.Where(c => c._predecessorId.HasValue)
                                  .ToDictionary(c => c._predecessorId.Value, c => c);

while (colorsByPredecessorId.ContainsKey(current._id))
{
    current = colorsByPredecessorId[current._id];
    sorted.Add(current);
}

return sorted;
```

Comment: Rather than excluding the root node from the lookup, and then doing a linear search through the collection to find the root node, you can just include the root node in the lookup and then get the root node from the lookup.  Your logic is also wrong, you need to use the nodes ID, not it's parent id, to fetch the following node from the lookup.  The answer also lacks any description of what's going on here, dramatically reducing its quality.

Comment: Was midway through fixing that error when you commented. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score -2):

I posted the same thing as ryanyuyu but deleted it as he was a few seconds faster, but seeing as it seems to do what you want and he hasn't submitted it as answer yet, I will:

```
var orderedColors = colors.OrderBy(x => x.predecessorId);
```

Which provides the output like so:

[image]

So I'm not sure what you mean in your comment

> solution here would only work if we could guarantee that the predecessorIds are always in numeric order. If I changed the predecessor IDs to reverse the order, it wouldn't work anymore

It doesn't matter what order the source data is in. That's the point of `OrderBy`. It puts the collection in the order you dictate. Unless you can clarify on the requirements, this should suffice.

Comment: Oh I understand what the OP means.  It really is a (reversed?) linked list.  So the predecessor ids could have a "correct" ordering of `1, 2, 5, 4, 3`.  And ordering on them is completely irrelevant.